# Opening a file on IIS

Tags: c#, iis

I have a program which creates word, excel and powerpoint files. All my code works fine on client side. As automation of office tools is not possible on server side I used third party API's like Aspose and OfficeWriter to create the documents. I used below mentioned code to open, after creating the file.

```
string paths = Server.MapPath("~/Data/" + TextBox1.Text + ".docx" );
        Process prc = new Process();
        prc.StartInfo.FileName = paths;
        prc.Start();
```

This code will not open the file from IIS, even Aspose and OfficeWriter are meant to work on server. Then I tried to open .jpg file using this code on IIS. That also does not work. I think prs.start() will not work on IIS. Is there any alternative way to open the file. I dont want to open the file as if we are downloding an attachment.

Comment: Explain what "doesn't work" means. You get exceptions? What are they? Some other behavior? What is it? What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is supposed to happen when a file is "opened" in IIS?

Comment: Where do you want to open the file? You seem to be working on an ASP.NET application which runs on the server. How exactly do you expect this file to open?

Comment: You have to give your app rights to the files.   Also is "Process" the  one from "System.Diagnostics"

Comment: @Oded, When i click the button on client side the .docx file will open as a UI. When I click the button when running through IIS, I'll not get any UI, instead the page will be running and running and not yield any results.

Comment: @jsobo, the process is from system.diagnostics. I have given the permission by going to dcomcnfg -> Component service -> Computers -> my computer -> DCOM config

Comment: What do you expect to happen with this code when it runs through IIS???

Comment: Actually I'm creating a web application which acts exactly as google document. IN my application the user creates the document, automatically it is stored in his database. He can view all the documents he has created & uploaded in gridview, and view them and share them with other users.

Comment: Yeah what you are doing will cause an app to start on the "server" the user (client) will not be able to see it.  Oded has the right idea.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is trying to call the application associated with the `.docx` extension, wherever it is running.

If this is *server side* code, this is not likely to give you any useful results (assuming there is an association defined, the application pool identity running the site will now have this file opened. It can't do anything with it now).

You should probably be using [`Response.WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f369a2by.aspx) - this will send the file to the client.